# Part of EXIF data read by exif_read_data() is corrupted

Tags: php, exif

When I read the EXIF data from a raw file with exif_read_data() a lot of the data gets corrupted. Or so I think.

The file I'm trying to read is a DNG Raw file from a Pentax K-x camera.
Here is a demo: http://server.patrikelfstrom.se/exif/?file=_IGP6211.DNG
(I've added a standard JPEG from a Canon EOS 1000D as comparison)

I get no errors on this site and it seems to include data that exif_read_data() doesn't return.
http://regex.info/exif.cgi

And the corrupt data I'm talking about is: `...”¯/Ñ³f/ÇZ/íÔ.ƒ.9:./<ñ.TÛ¨.zâh!o†!™˜...`
And: UndefinedTag:0xC65A

The server is running PHP version 5.5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because the data isn't **human readable** doesn't mean it's garbage.

Those values that you're seeing are *private EXIF fields* which are left up to the implementer to determine.  They could be binary data, they could be text, they could be anything.  [This listing](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/private.html) can help you determine what some of those values are.

For example, tag 0xC634 is [DNGPrivateData](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/dngprivatedata.html) which is data specifically for *programs* that deal with DNG files.

Answer (score 1):

You can map the undefined tags to what they most likely are using this file:

```
https://github.com/peterhudec/image-metadata-cruncher/blob/master/includes/exif-mapping.php
```

It looks like your script is dying on `0xc634 => 'SR2Private'`

Looking here http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/Pentax.html it looks like it is used to store information about the flash on the camera?  I don't know for sure, but it probably is not imporant information, and probably not meant to be viewed in text format.

I would probably just make a list of what keys it seems to die on, loop through the exif data, see if it starts with `undefinedkey:` and either rename the key to the mapped one, or unset those items:

```
$bad_keys = array('0xc634', ..., '0xc723');

foreach ( $exif as $key => $value ) {
    if ( strtolower( substr( $key, 0, 13 ) ) == 'undefinedtag:' ) {
        //use the file with the map of undefined tags
        //either change the key, or unset it if it's one 
        //that seems to be corrupt
    }
}
```